# Try/Catch on user input with a Switch statement to verify the User Input but String variable comes out of scope

Tags: switch-statement, try-catch, java.util.scanner, user-input

I'm having trouble applying a try/catch on user input which I then pass to a switch to verify the user input. the String variable holding the user input and passed to the Switch becomes out of scope. How can I make this work?

```
try { 
String name = sc.next();
} catch (Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();}

switch (name) {
```

I get a "cannot find symbol" error pointing at the String name variable inside the switch. I'm positive its bc it's out of scope. Is there anyway I can make this work? I need to add a try/catch clause for a project and this seems the most viable option.